# Getting "The HOME environmental variable changed out from under us!" in system log

Tags: command-line, osx-lion

In Mac OS X Lion, I am seeing many lines in my system.log file indicating that the HOME env variable has been changed.

```
19/02/2012 23:47:16.204 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.PreferenceSyncAgent[19914]) The HOME environmental variable changed out from under us!
19/02/2012 23:47:16.205 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.PreferenceSyncAgent[19914]) In a future build of the OS, this error will be fatal.
```

Another example:

```
19/02/2012 23:47:19.494 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.locationmenu[19917]) The HOME environmental variable changed out from under us!
19/02/2012 23:47:19.494 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.locationmenu[19917]) In a future build of the OS, this error will be fatal.
```

Any idea how I can check what's changing this variable?  The system is very stable but I want to avoid future problems.